# Blender energy effects

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, effects

I'm trying to have one of my character fire a ki blast from his palm (anime style). Now in terms of the effects would i do that while animating my models or would i model and animate the blast itself during the composite phase of my project?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload reference images of what you want to achieve. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are on 2.8, animate the blast. use emission. model it. use bloom effect. If you're on 2.79 do it on post.

Comment: I'm using 2.79. What do you mean by do it on post??

Comment: I mean you can use mask to create a roto shape on your finalized animation. You (draw) on the compositor.